# Is there a way to find the row of a given cell in an ordered matrix?

Tags: math

For example, given a matrix:

```
    01|02|03|04|05
    06|07|08|09|10
    11|12|13|14|15
```

And knowing that the matrix is 5x3, is there a way that if given the value '7', that we can know it is in row 2? The case is that the matrix is always ordered from 1 to n, starting from 0.

Lastly, the matrix is stored linearly in a zero based array.

Comment: Do you want a zero based solution or not? Your accepted answer is not zero based.

Comment: Another thing to consider is whether or not your "row 1" is actually considered row 1 or row 0 in your matrix. There is a lot of ambiguity here.

Comment: Yes, nothing as stated is zero-based.  The top-left element is 1, and it seems to have (row,col)=(1,1).

Comment: And, as someone pointed out in an answer (that has apparently been deleted), what you have here is a 3x5 matrix, not a 5x3 matrix.

Comment: Premature acceptication for sure.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Question states the series (the values, not the indices) starts at 1 and the number of columns is 5. How the series is stored is not relevant. The question remains the same with or without mentioning the array.

Comment: rvarcher is correct. The values start at 1. The answer happens to work without modification with a zero based array. As far as I see it is the correct answer.

Comment: @ApplePie: on a zero-based array, the accepted answer would not work for the first element in each row.  i.e, the 2nd row would start with element 5, but ceil(5/5)=1, which is not the correct answer.

Comment: Kip, you're correct, I am thinking one thing and writing another. When I tested his answer, I tested it by using the index, not the value, which works since I'm going off the index. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
row = ceiling(7 / 5)  or   ceiling(position / width)
```

Comment: Why was this modded down? Is it not correct? It seems correct and to the point.

Comment: I didn't downmod it... but I would point out that while this is the correct answer for a math class, it isn't an ideal *programming* solution because you'd need to do unnecessary floating point math.  Also, if position and width are integers, a naive implementation of ceil(pos/width) would actually be equivalent ceil(floor(pos/width))=floor(pos/width).  This depends on programming language of course, some will use floating point math for all division unless you go out of your way.

Answer (score 4):

if it is 0-based:

> row: n / width
>   col: n % width

In your example, you say it is zero-based, but it is actually starting at 1, and you count the top-left element as (row,col)=(1,1), so you'd need to adjust the math:

> row: (n-1) / width + 1
>   col: (n-1) % width + 1

In your case, n=7, width= 5:

> row = (7-1)/5 + 1 = 1+1 = 2
>   col = (7-1)%5 + 1 = 1+1 = 2

Note: I'm using standard programmer's integer math, where "a/b" really means "floor(a/b)".

Comment: Bad communication on my part, I meant it is stored in a zero based array, not that the first value is zero based.

Answer (score 0):

```
Let X be your index
-------------------
column = X % width
row    = ceiling(X / width)
```

**Edit**: Seems to work now that I made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is stored in a [row-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) order, then the row indices map to the element index as follows:

```
 rowIndex = (elementIndex - 1) / numcolumns
 columnIndex = (elementIndex % numcolumns) - 1
```

This is always integer division -- so no remainders. You will get the row and column indices as starting from 0.

It is left as an exercise to figure out what happens in column-major layout.

Comment: But 7 - 1 / 4 is 1.5, leaving 1, and in a 3x4 matrix, 7 is in the 3rd row, or index 2 in a zero based array. Unless I'm missing something your answer is not right?

Comment: In your case, numcolumns = 5. So, rowIndex = (7 - 1) / 5 = 6 / 5 = 1 (since indices start at 0, this indicates the second row). Also, columnIndex = 7 % 5 - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1 (the second column).